# array is overwritten by the last element in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, codeigniter-datamapper

The result stored in `$g` is 1 and 2. The following code I've written below, my `$array['music']` stores only the last element that is 2. But what I want is to execute my sql query 2 times under foreach and match the value of `$g` which is 1 and 2 with `mu_id` (`mu_id` is the column name from another table `music`) and store all the rows data of row 1 and 2 in to `$array['music']`.

It is storing only for the second row (2) not for 1 or it is overwriting it when it is executing for the second time inside loop. If there is any logic to make it work then please let me know.

```
    foreach($genre as $g)
    {
        echo $g;
        echo "<br>";
        $array['music'] = $m -> where('mu_id', $g ) -> get();
    }
```

Comment: What's $g?  What's $m? Give your variables appropriate names, so they're easier to follow. We don't need to learn our ABCs again.

Comment: @Truth: The CI Datamapper docs use single letter variables in all their examples, so this is probably just copying those examples. I agree it's a bad habit, but in this case, I would assume `$g` is "genre" and `$m` is "music". I also would just use the full word.

Comment: @madmartigan I'm well aware of that. I'm just stating that he shouldn't do it himself, as well as copying examples blindly without understanding the basics of arrays.

Comment: @Truth: Oh ok... I'll take care of that from next time onward...

Comment: $g is for genre and $m for music table ( object of music class).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're redeclaring the entire array each time rather than adding to it, use this instead:

```
foreach($genre as $g)
{
    $array['music'][] = $m->where('mu_id', $g)->get();
}
```

Or even better, less queries:

```
$array['music'] = $m->where_in('mu_id', $genre)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. As I am new to codeigniter and datamapper , I was wondering how to make it work. This is something like magic to me. I am really happy as this is now working perfectly. What a rapid reply!!! Thanks once again... :)

Comment: Both CI and DM have really good docs, make sure to read them frequently. That said, this was just a fundamental PHP mistake, PHP has really good docs too, make sure to reference them frequently as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store all the data in an array you should be using  `$array['music'][]` instead of  `$array['music']`