# PHP Array is overwritten when it exits the while loop where the values are assigned

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a table called statussen in my database with 10 colors. Now I want to put those colors in an array so I can make use of them, I placed 2 markers in my code because at Marker1 the array is filled completely normal with the 10 colors. But as soon as I get out of the while loop (where Marker2 is), the only color that is left is the very last one.
I also found this question on here : [array is overwritten by the last element in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380636/array-is-overwritten-by-the-last-element-in-php).
But I don't think it applies to my problem.
Thanks ahead for all the help

```
$colors = array();
$result = mysqli_query($_SESSION['conn'], "SELECT kleur FROM statussen;");
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) 
{
    for ($i = 0;$i < 10; $i++)
    {
        $colors[$i] = $row[$i];
    }
    //Marker1
}
//Marker2
```

Comment: You don't need the inner loop. Right now, you're filling up an array with ten identical elements, ten separate times.

Comment: You just need the `while()` loop and `$colors[] = $row[0];`

Comment: @NigelRen Thank you! This did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of my understanding :

You are using while loop which loop through array one by so there is only one record inside while loop at a time and so does for `for` loop(which is not required)

The second thing is you are adding index `$colors[$i]`. Every time for loop get initialised it set `$i = 0` and this means that it set value to `$colors[0] = $row[$i]` so that it gets override.

You can directly use code like this:

```
$colors = array();
$result = mysqli_query($_SESSION['conn'], "SELECT kleur FROM statussen;");
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) 
{
    $colors[] = $row[$i];
}
//Marker2
```

notice that there is no index provide to colors array `$colors[]`, in this case PHP automatically add increment index to it starting from 0.